# Transform JSON key:value pairs in flat structure into key:value tree structure

Tags: python, json, data-structures

It is possible to transform list of key:value pairs of data in the same "level" (flat structure) into a tree structure key:value of that data?

Example:

From:

```
[{"COD": "20000", "VAL": "Fanerozoico"}, {"COD": "23000", "VAL": "Cenozoico"}, {"COD": "23300", "VAL": "Quaternario"}, {"COD": "23310", "VAL": "Pleistocenico"}, {"COD": "23314", "VAL": "Pleistocenico Superior"}, {"COD": "23200", "VAL": "Neogénico"}, {"COD": "23220", "VAL": "Pliocénico"}, {"COD": "23222", "VAL": "Piacenziano"}]
```

Into:

```
{
"Fanerozoico": {
    "COD": "20000",
    "Cenozoico": {
        "COD": "23000",
        "Quaternario": {
            "COD": "23300",
            "Pleistocenico": {
                "COD": "23310",
                "Pleistocenico Superior": {
                    "COD": "23314"
                }
            }
        },
        "Neogenico": {
            "COD": "23200",
            "Pliocenico": {
                "COD": "23220",
                "Piacenziano": {
                    "COD": "23222"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is it LIST of keyvales ? [{"COD": "20000", "VAL": "Fanerozoico"}, {"COD": "23000", "VAL": "Cenozoico"}, {"COD": "23300", "VAL": "Quaternario"}, {"COD": "23310", "VAL": "Pleistocenico"}, {"COD": "23314", "VAL": "Pleistocenico Superior"}]  ?

Comment: Yes @Backtrack is a list

Comment: Can you explain why `Quaternario` and `Neogenico` end up at the same level ? I don't see the logic here.

Comment: Ah on second look it seems to be structured by firsts chars of the COD, am I correct ?

Comment: An actual list of key: value would be [("20000", "Fanerozoico"), ("23000", "Cenozoico"), ]

Comment: You are right @Guillaume, COD key chars give the level of the pair/object. At level 0 we have 1 object (20000 : Fanerozoico). At level 1, 1 objects (23000 : Cenozoico). At level 2, 2 objects (23300 : Quaternario and 23200 : Neogenico).... This is just a part of the full structure which is better to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt (that works but might not be the best solution):

```
mylist = [
    {"COD": "20000", "VAL": "Fanerozoico"},
    {"COD": "23000", "VAL": "Cenozoico"},
    {"COD": "23300", "VAL": "Quaternario"},
    {"COD": "23310", "VAL": "Pleistocenico"},
    {"COD": "23314", "VAL": "Pleistocenico Superior"},
    {"COD": "23200", "VAL": "Neogénico"},
    {"COD": "23220", "VAL": "Pliocénico"},
    {"COD": "23222", "VAL": "Piacenziano"}
]


COD_LEN = 5

class CODMapper(object):
    def __init__(self, kvlist):
        self._map = {item["COD"]: item["VAL"] for item in kvlist}

    def getchildren(self, key):
        ' return a list of all direct children of a given key '
        if len(key) == COD_LEN:
            return []
        suffix = "0"*(COD_LEN-len(key)-1)
        return [(cod, val) for cod, val in self._map.items()
                        if  cod.startswith(key)
                        and cod.endswith(suffix)
                        and cod[len(key)] != "0"
                ]

    def todict(self, key=""):
        ' Creates the dictionnary structured as you want '
        children = self.getchildren(key)
        result = {}
        for cod, val in children:
            inner_dict = {"COD": cod}
            new_key = cod[:len(key)+1]
            inner_dict.update(self.todict(new_key))
            result[val] = inner_dict
        return result



from pprint import pprint
pprint(CODMapper(mylist).todict())
```

Will output:

```
{'Fanerozoico': {'COD': '20000',
    'Cenozoico': {'COD': '23000',
        'Neogénico': {'COD': '23200',
            'Pliocénico': {'COD': '23220',
                'Piacenziano': {'COD': '23222'}}},
        'Quaternario': {'COD': '23300',
            'Pleistocenico': {'COD': '23310',
                'Pleistocenico Superior': {'COD': '23314'}}}}}}
```

Comment: list comprehension in function __init__(self, kvlist) gives error : **"string indices must be integers, not str"**. kvlist is a list of dicts, where is the issue? thank you

Comment: You mean dict comprehension, right ? Which version of Python are you using ? It works for me on 3.5.

Comment: Replace the line by `self._map = dict((item["COD"], item["VAL"]) for item in kvlist)` if dict comprehension is not supported in your python version.

Comment: Yes dict comprehension. Using V 2.7.8. Using dict instead of {} did not solve the issue. Created a gist just in case is better to catch the problem : https://gist.github.com/abreufreire/36cced44d1ab1366634dc632dc86e27e

Comment: Commented your gist with a fix.